# How do I associate a Clone to it's Parent in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model of say Apps and each App contains a bunch of users, and a reference to the store type, and has the properties, name, app_id,  version,  and  price.

I want to be able to create clones of this app, which has all the same values, save for version, and store type.

I'd like to do this by adding a property/column to my app called "Is_clone", and I'd like a second table called AppToClone, which has two columns  App and Clone.
In each row, I'll have say App:1 , Clone:[2,5,7,26]

This way I can edit each clone as its own app, but at the same time I can apply any changes in an app to all its clones.

I've set up the database for AppToClone but I'm stuck on how to create this association within the App Model itself.  Examples I've found so far such as the gem rails_lookup_tables seems to only allow a single value rather than an array in the AppToClone table.

Currently in my App model I have the following line:
`:has_many :apps, through: :appstoclones`
But this doesn't feel correct to me, and I'm not sure how to build that database over time.

Feeling kinda stupid here, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

So the has_many and belongs_to association stores the data in a different way than the question indicates.  I would use single table inheritance, having a Clone model inherit from the App model.

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clones
end

class Clone < App
  belongs_to :app
end
```

You would need to have an app_id and type on your app table (strange I know), so your clone can be associated.  What you would be able to do then is query your clone as an App.

```
Clone.last.is_a? App
-> true
```

What I think is closest to what you actually want though, is outlined in section [2.10 Self Joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) of the Ruby on Rails Guides.

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clones, class_name: "App",
                      foreign_key: "parent_app_id"

  belongs_to :parent_app, class_name: "App"
end
```

You need to create the foreign_key in a migration.

To implement the is_clone:

```
def is_clone?
  !!self.parent_app_id
end
```

To implement the AppToClone:

```
def clone_ids
  self.clones.all.map(&id)
end

# Check it in the console:
App.last.clone_ids
-> [2,5,7,26]
```

The biggest concern here is thinking that a table will have a row with one column holding an array.  That is not normalized!  Normal associations work by having the foreign keys as seen in these examples, one per row.  If you have a complex has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, the table that holds keys has two columns, each with one id.

Per the request in the comment below (self join update):

```
def clone_me
  self.clones << self.clone
end

> new_cloned_app = App.last.clone_me
```

The reference for using has_many is found: [In the rails guide here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference).  Feel free to use a different helper function.  Also, the returned value must be `.save`ed

Comment: When you write :# This is not in the class definition,  Where does it go?

Comment: I moved the comment to where it was supposed to be.  Originally I was going to create a method that performed the function, but as soon as I wrote the comment, I realized it should have been in the model.  I thought I removed it, good catch.

Comment: Great thanks. The last thing I don't quite get, is how do I create a clone? I call create and pass in the parent_app_id?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are looking for a *has-many belongs-to relationship*.

For the has-many part: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

For the belongs-to part: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

One model would be the **app**, the other **clone**, where the clone table would store the the same fields an app has, as well as the additional fields needed for a **clone** instance. By inheriting the clone model from the app model which inherits from ActiveRecord, one can use a clone in the code where an app is used.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear with which step I'm stuck on. I have that part, I just don't understand how to create them and make sure the AppToClone table keeps all the connections clear.

Comment: I'm ussing currently  :has_many :apps, through: :apptoclones  but I'm not sure its correct

Comment: If I understand you correctly: One app _has many_ clones, one clone _belongs to_ one app?  If that is correct, just model it : )  You only need a _has-many-through_ relationship in case you want to store additional data in the linking table.

Comment: clones are apps, the only difference between them in the model is the value in the "is_clone" column.

Comment: Mainly because I don't want to duplicate all the controlers that already exist

Comment: Do I get this right? This means, you store 2 or more identical rows in the database with the only difference in the is_clone field? This sounds like bad design.

Comment: Apps already exist and have lots of code associated with them. I need clones to do everything an app does, cause it is an app, it's just filled with another app's data.

Comment: They will also have version and storetype as different values.